# in curl what is the load time for url request

Tags: php, curl

i am finding Load Time for the url request using curl
and using

```
$info=curl_getinfo($handle);
print_r($info);
```

which is the load time

- pretranver time
- namelook time
- connect time
- start transvertime
- look up time

if not in these then how do i find and also primary_ip is the ip address of the url

Answer (score 2):

Here is a short example

https://josephscott.org/archives/2011/10/timing-details-with-curl/

I think you need all of them. Then all of them is part of the total time.